# How to exclude code from running inside requestAnimationFrame

Tags: next.js, paperjs, matter.js

[image: screen shot (not showing flashing)]

Hi all, in a nextjs app Im using requestAnimationFrame and matter.js to animate shapes created using paper.js. The shapes are created with a javascript Class inside a forEach loop. Each shape (RegularPolygon) has a random number of sides. When I run the code, Matter.js takes care of the physics but the logic to create the random sides also animates creating a cool (but undesirable strobing effect) of continuously randomising the number of sides of the RegularPolygon. I'm looking for a way of creating the shapes with random sides, once, and then animating them. Thanks in advance.
[link to netlify site](https://6202f36326cfaf09cff34413--flashing.netlify.app/)

```
import { Engine, Render, World, Bodies } from 'matter-js';
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { paper } from 'paper';

const random = (min, max) => {
    return Math.random() * min + Math.random() * max + min;
};

function Canvas(props) {
    const scene = useRef();
    const engine = useRef(Engine.create());
    const paperRef = useRef();
    const raf = useRef();
    console.log(random);
    useEffect(() => {
        const time = 0;
        window.addEventListener('load', () => {
            paper.setup(paperRef.current);

            const cw = document.body.clientWidth;
            const ch = document.body.clientHeight;

            const render = Render.create({
                element: scene.current,
                engine: engine.current,
                options: {
                    width: cw,
                    height: ch,
                    wireframes: false,
                    background: 'transparent',
                },
            });
            World.add(engine.current.world, [
                Bodies.rectangle(cw / 2, -10, cw, 20, {
                    isStatic: true,
                }),
                Bodies.rectangle(-10, ch / 2, 20, ch, {
                    isStatic: true,
                    fillStyle: '#F35e66',
                }),
                Bodies.rectangle(cw / 2, ch + 10, cw, 20, {
                    isStatic: true,
                    fillStyle: '#F35e66',
                }),
                Bodies.rectangle(cw + 10, ch / 2, 20, ch, {
                    isStatic: true,
                    fillStyle: '#F35e66',
                }),
            ]);

            Engine.run(engine.current);
            Render.run(render);
            const balls = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
                balls.push(
                    Bodies.circle(Math.random() * cw, 0, 80, {
                        density: Math.random(),
                        friction: 0.01,
                        frictionAir: 0.00001,
                        restitution: 0.8,
                        render: {
                            fillStyle: '#F35e66',
                            strokeStyle: 'black',
                            lineWidth: 1,
                        },
                    })
                );
            }

            var ball = Bodies.circle(0, 0, 20, {
                density: 0.04,
                friction: 0.01,
                frictionAir: 0.00001,
                restitution: 0.8,
                render: {
                    fillStyle: '#F35e66',
                    strokeStyle: 'black',
                    lineWidth: 1,
                },
            });
            for (let i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
                World.add(engine.current.world, [balls[i]]);
            }
            const shapes = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
                shapes.push(
                    new paper.Path.RegularPolygon({
                        position: new paper.Point([
                            balls[i].position.x,
                            balls[i].position.y,
                        ]),
                        sides: Math.floor(random(0, 8)),
                        radius: 100,
                        fillColor: 'tomato',
                    })
                );
            }
            class Shape {
                constructor(x, y, angle) {
                    this.angle = angle;
                    this.x = x;
                    this.y = y;
                    this.draw();
                    this.shape = new paper.Path.RegularPolygon({
                        position: new paper.Point([this.x, this.y]),
                        sides: Math.floor(random(0, 8)),
                        radius: 100,
                        fillColor: 'tomato',
                    });
                }
                draw() {
                    // this.shape.rotate(this.angle);
                }
            }
            console.log(ball);
            const callback = () => {
                // paper.view.update();
                paper.project.clear();

                balls.forEach((ball) => {
                    new Shape(ball.position.x, ball.position.y, ball.angle);
                    // let shape = new paper.Path.RegularPolygon({
                    //  position: new paper.Point([
                    //      ball.position.x,
                    //      ball.position.y,
                    //  ]),
                    //  sides: Math.floor(Math.random() * 8),
                    //  radius: 100,
                    //  fillColor: 'tomato',
                    // });
                    // shape.rotate(ball.angle);
                });
                const shape = new paper.Path.RegularPolygon({
                    position: new paper.Point([
                        ball.position.x,
                        ball.position.y,
                    ]),
                    sides: 5,
                    radius: 100,
                    fillColor: 'tomato',
                });
                shape.rotate(ball.angle);
                raf.current = requestAnimationFrame(callback);
            };

            raf.current = requestAnimationFrame(callback);

            return () => {
                cancelAnimationFrame(raf.current);
                Render.stop(render);
                World.clear(engine.current.world);
                Engine.clear(engine.current);
                render.canvas.remove();
                render.canvas = null;
                render.context = null;
                render.textures = {};
            };
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className=''>
            <div className='paper'>
                <canvas
                    resize='true'
                    ref={paperRef}
                    style={{
                        width: '100%',
                        height: '100%',
                        position: 'fixed',
                        top: 0,
                        left: 0,
                    }}
                />
            </div>
            <div
                ref={scene}
                style={{
                    display: 'none',
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '100%',
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                }}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Canvas;
```

Comment: Simply move the `new Shape`/`new paper.Path.RegularPolygon`/`new paper.Point` stuff out of the loop? You want to create that one time up front, then loop and draw it.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I'll give it a go. I thought it needed to be inside the loop so that it animates. I guess I can try and update x,y inside the loop?

Comment: Yup, that's what I'd try. Same objects, different positions. Update rotation as well. If you get stuck, let me know and I'll see if I can write an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!